# Break long words on small screens

Tags: php, css, word-wrap

I have this line:

```php
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>
```

That is part of a code element.

What I'm trying to do is to view the line on *small* screens (without horizontal scrolling).

I have tried to style both `<pre>` and `<code>` with the help of http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_text_effects.asp - and still the line doesn't break!

```css
code { 
  width: 90%;
  min-width: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 1rem;
  /* ... and now what? */
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [overflow-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) CSS property should fix your issue

```css
code {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;

  -ms-word-break: break-all;

  /* This is the dangerous one in WebKit, as it breaks things wherever */
  word-break: break-all;

  /* Instead use this non-standard one: */
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

Comment: additional info i took some info from [caniuse.com](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/)

Comment: ok it works perfect when it's one line. but what if there is couple of lines (inside pre element to view preety)? it seems the css not affecting on Small screens when it more than one line.

Comment: if I am not mistaken a <pre> element by definition is saying that it is preformatted.

Comment: so if i want to view piece of code on Small screens what should i use? for 1 line of code your answer is good. should i use maybe textarea instead of pre? what the PRO do? (:

Comment: Can you paste a sample of what your rendered HTML looks like possible in a snippet or fiddle

Answer (score 1):

All that you need is to add: `word-wrap: break-word;` 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-wrap

Comment: please don't quote w3schools is is well documented as not being the most accurate source I recommend instead [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap)

Comment: @happymacarts Yes, but if you send them a Mozzila Dev documentation link, most uninformed people would thik that this will works only on Firefox browser

Comment: @DermannDekovic perhaps that can be explained as part of the post, thanks for the edit, in question, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

```
code {
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

From [Mozzila Dev documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap)

This is working on:

- Google Chrome 4.0+
- Microsoft Edge 5.5+
- Firefox Mozzila 3.5+
- Safari 3.1+
- Opera 10.5+

Comment: sorry just replicated your post. i left it since it was a little more thurough

Comment: @happymacarts no problem, it is more thorough.